# Conditionally Format Specific words within cells of worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have data such that single cells contain multiple bit of info.

Using conditional formatting excel can recognise cells which contain a phrase however the conditional format is applied to the cell as a whole. I'm aiming to try and Highlight the Specific  text "Not Provided" in Red.

[image]

Looking online it looks like this will be a VBA solution.

To start, I have found the following code online however this doesnt appear to change the colour as desired.

```
Sub Test1()
  Dim strString$, x&
  Dim rngCell As Range
  
  strString = Range("B1").Value
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  For Each rngCell In Range("G1", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    With rngCell
      .Font.ColorIndex = 1
      For x = 1 To Len(.Text) - Len(strString) Step 1
        If Mid(.Text, x, Len(strString)) = strString Then .Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 5
      Next x
    End With
  Next rngCell
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If someone could point out either how I can get the code above working to explore if this will be useful for my purposes or even if someone knows how to conditionally format specific words that would be great. Ultimately I wish for every instance of "Not Provided" across the worksheet to be highlighted in this way.

Comment: Take the `q` off the end of `Next rngCellq`.  You use `For Each rngCell In R....` so you must use `Next rngCell` (or just `Next`, but better to have the variable to).

Comment: Please insert `Option Explicit` at the top of the module which will help to enforce you to declare all variable explicitly. You will get compile error saying that `rngCellq` is not defined the moment you insert that line and try to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InStr()` to find substring instead of For loop

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim strString As String, x As Long, rngCell As Range
  
    strString = Range("B1").Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each rngCell In Range("G1", Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        x = InStr(1, rngCell.Value2, strString, vbTextCompare)
        If x > 0 Then
            With rngCell
              .Font.ColorIndex = 1
              .Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 3    'red color
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To dynamically change the color of the text, as in conditional formatting, you can use the `Change` event:

```
'place it into the Worksheet module
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim strString As String, x As Long, rngCell As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("G"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    strString = Range("B1").Value
    
    For Each rngCell In rng
        x = InStr(1, rngCell.Value2, strString, vbTextCompare)
        If x > 0 Then
            With rngCell
              .Font.ColorIndex = 1
              .Characters(x, Len(strString)).Font.ColorIndex = 3    'red color
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```